# Solr Transform to split data into multiple fields

Tags: sql, solr, solr6

I am Trying to create a new Core in Solr and import data into it, but I am displaying this data on Kendo grid and I need to display data from one column from the DB in two different fields(columns)

Here is the Data in the column that i need to split into two different columns

> 10680756-1000-RAT

I need to split the "10680756" in 1 called called A and in another column called B

this is my data config and schema

```
<entity name="myTable" pk="testingId" 
query="select * from myTable" 
  >
  <field column="codeStatus" name="codeStatus"/> (this column has the data "10680756-1000-RAT")
```

I need to show it like:

```
Code Status            A           B
10680756-1000-RAT    10680756     1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Update Request Processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors) to split the field into two separate fields (and still keep the original field if needed), for example by using a [StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html) and writing a small piece of javascript to split the field and add two new fields.

Another option is to use the [PatternReplaceFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory) or [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) together with two `copyField` instructions. Use the PatternReplaceFilter to remove anything *except* for the part of the token you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible for you to provide an example?

Comment: I got it to work via the regexTransformer

i used this

`<field column="dstcol" regex="^.{0}(.*?)(?=-)" sourceColName="sourcecol"/>`